# Java HttpClient Request return 403 status while postman returns the intended response

Tags: java, httpclient, steam, steambot

Tried to request with postman which gives desired response.

The java code used for making the same request is as below fails with a 403 status.

```java
String url = "https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198865293952/440/2?l=english&count=5000";
String cookiesString = "sessionid=" + generateSessionId() + ";steamCountry=IN%7Ce744269b3c4e531facb33ecaff29eb44";

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36")
                .header("Accept", "*/*")
                .header("Cookie", cookiesString)
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.statusCode()); //prints 403
System.out.println(response.body()); // prints       �+�� O��%
```

```java
/**
* Generates a Steam Session Id.
* @return sessionId.
*/
public static String generateSessionId() {
   return new BigInteger(96, new Random()).toString(16);
}
```

Postman request does not need any headers(Not even User-Agent, only Host is kept, No cookies are needed) at all to get the desired response. Even navigating to link in browser shows the json response.

[PostMan request ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5TZL.png)

[Postman Request Image with cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOJKE.png)

Thank you. Have a great day.

Comment: Your Postman screenshot shows two cookies though. Take a look at those. Even in Chrome I get a 403 so that seems like default behaviour when unauthenticated.

Comment: The request urls are different, perhaps the uri in your code requires some form of Auth, while the one in postman doesnt

Comment: @FreeBird seems likely the cookies have the auth/session details stored?

Comment: @Gavin yes that's what I suspect too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, the cookies were because I made the same request before without cookies and then steam set the cookies of sessionid and steamCountry. I am using Postman desktop application and not chrome plugin, is it still someway connected?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the 2 cookies you have in postman and not in the java code are responsible for having the 403 response.

Postman is a google chrome plugin so when connecting w/ chrome, maybe you stored in the cache the cookies.

You also need to add them to the java code.

Comment: So I did add the two cookies to the request. I have updated the above question with it. Still has the same response. I even tries with the same sessionid as that of postman. Also I know how the sessionid work as I use it with my steam trade bot there this method of calculating sessionid works fine.

Comment: Also added image with cookies. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Thanks for all your answers and replies.

So I found that the inventory that I was trying to access was set visible to friends only, so response was 403. So it does work for inventories that are set to public.

I am sorry, I should have check it first.

What I still dont understand is how did the postman desktop client get the intended response? I understand that chrome was able to get the inventory because I have active steam login with cookies that would have been send but postman request did not have any cookies other than sessionid and country. If someone could explain how this happens it would really help me.